# $\omega$ , modulo operation, Boolean algebras

Tags: functions, notation, set-theory, boolean-algebra

In [this](http://shelah.logic.at/nonstructure/VII.pdf) paper of Shelah on the page 6 in the -3rd line, what it means $$\bigwedge_{i<\kappa}h(i)=i \text{ mod } \omega$$? I just do not understand the notation.

Comment: Sure, it's fine to *not* copy the whole page. But at least specify that $h\colon\kappa\to\omega\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can understand this would be that if $i=\delta+n$ for some $n<\omega$ and a limit ordinal $\delta$, then $h(i)=n$. In other words, $i$ and $h(i)$ are the same number of successors from a limit ordinal or $0$.

Of course the $\bigwedge$ is just an infinitary conjunction, so in other words $\forall i<\kappa$, etc.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Why is $0$ excluded from the range of $h$ ?

Comment: Ask Saharon. I don't know...

Comment: I've got it: $h(i)-1$ must be a nonnegative index in a tuple $(s_0,...,s_{h(i)-1})$.